# (For Rails/Angular app): subdomains: client-side, server-side, or both?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, subdomain

Disclaimers:

1. I'm sure I'm not explaining this well. Please bear with
2. I'll use slack here, as that's probably an example most people are familiar
   with
3. I've read the other SO subdomain posts, but nothing seems to fit this situation. Please let me know if I'm wrong about that

Overview: most of what I've read about subdomains assume a single "choke point" to control the subdomain. For example, after login, re-route to the user's subdomain: myname.slack.com

(I think the proper term for this, is using subdomains for a multi-tenant app. But in this case, the app has subdomains, but not for multi-tenancy purposes).

However, is it possible to write an app (if you don't have a single "choke point") such that different navigation tabs and links go back and forth between the aforementioned subdomain and the general domain?

For example, I think once you sign into slack, every link after that pertains solely to your subdomain. But what if they wanted to include some links that routed to either the general slack.com domain, or some other subdomain (help.slack.com, for example).

It seems there are three strategies:

- "Brute force" client-side: set the base URL for every single link
- Client-side interceptor: intercept every HTTP request, and apply some logic to set the domain (I was going this route but ran into some CORS issues)
- Server-side logic: it seems that you could redirect_to the_path_url(subdomain: 'my_subdomain') based on some logic about the incoming request?

Does anyone have experience with this, and has any tips or advice if any of the aforementioned (or something else) is a good way to proceed? Please let me know where this question is unclear, and I will improve it. Thank you!